# Jquery adding array of values to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a json object like the below

```
 {
    "Name":"UnitedStates",
      "Info":[
        {"StateName":"Washington",
              "Commands":[
                       {"Type":"Men","Parameter":"10000"}, 
                       {"Type":"Women","Parameter":"30000"}
                     ]},
        {"StateName":"California",
               "Commands":[
                        {"Type":"Kids","Parameter":"20000"}
                          ]}
                     ]}
```

I am trying the below
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/575542/)

How can I add array of values to existing blank object.

```
    var CountryName = 'UnitedStates';

    var Data = {
        Name: CountryName,
        Info: [
        commands :[]
        ]
       }

    Data.Info.push({'StateName': 'washington'});
    Data.Info.commands.push(
    {'Type': 'Men'},
     {'Parameter': '1000'},

    );


     $('.displayJsonBlock').empty();
    $('.displayJsonBlock').append('<pre><code>' + JSON.stringify(TemplateData) + '</pre></code>')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the error console output, you'll see it's giving you a syntax error because `Info` is trying to be both an object and an array at the same time:

```
Info: [
    commands :[]
]
```

If you want to push into `Info` it needs to be an array, but that means you can't define properties in the literal like this. If you want to define properties like this it needs to be a an object like:

```
Info: {
    commands :[]
}
```

But then you can't push.

I think what you're looking for is:

```js
var CountryName = 'UnitedStates';

var Data = {
  Name: CountryName,
  Info: [] // info is just an array
}

Data.Info.push({
  'StateName': 'washington',
  commands: []               // each element of Info is an object with a commands array
});
Data.Info[0].commands.push(  // you need to define which element of info. Here it's the first
    {'Type': 'Men'}, 
    {'Parameter': '1000'},
);
console.log(Data)
```

Of course you don't need to do two pushes you can push the whole object including `commands`:

```
Data.Info.push({
  'StateName': 'washington',
  commands: [
    {'Type': 'Men'}, 
    {'Parameter': '1000'}
   ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the structure of JSON data is incorrect, I think you do something like this

```
var CountryName = 'UnitedStates';

var Data = {
    Name: CountryName,
    Info: [
      {commands :[]}
    ]
   }
```

After

```
Data.Info.push({'StateName': 'washington'});
Data.Info['commands'] = [{'Type': 'Men'}, {'Parameter': '1000'}];
```

There is a good way, but I do not know if it is what you want.

Comment: This will only get you one `commands` property on `Data`, whereas the desired JSON has a commands element on every element of `Info`.

Comment: Yes, I saw the structure after :/